# Are "alternative" history questions allowed?

Tags: discussion

By this, I am referring to actual specific events that could have occurred had a specific historical event had happened differently (not necessarily the broad scope that is often used in the literary alternate history genre).

Or would this be too much into discussion territory?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of all SE sites is to ask questions that can be clearly and concisely answered. Any questions that can only be answered with subjective, speculative answers are not appropriate for this site. Here is a link to some more detailed information on this.

https://history.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: No worries at all, I find that it is always best to ask first.

Comment: Hmmm it would seem that my asking of 'regular' historical questions are no good either. Very snarky response to my latest question.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Steve and my opinion is that alternative history questions are too speculative. Some users turn them into factual questions by asking, "What did historian X think would have happened had event Y occurred?" Although the general consensus seems to be that these are OK, I think they are too localized.

Comment: That is a very good point, alternate timelines would be increasingly speculative the further the point of divergence is.